# Using SD or SDHC through SPI in Coldfire system

Tags: linux, spi, sdhc

If I use [ColdFire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freescale_ColdFire) and [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus), does it matter if the [SD card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital) is SDHC or standard SD?

Since I can write the uClinux kernel and whatever application, can we say whether I can use the SDHC depends my programming but not hardware? It's just socket to connect to the microcontroller, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use the SDHC as well as normal SD.  I used spi in the coldfire and correctly written file to it.